# How to get the mouse coordinates stored in a variable in open layers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a code that displays the mouse position outside of the map in openlayers !
what if I want to save those coordinates when I call the js mouse events onmousedown and onmouseup ?

I have the following code :

```
const mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

const map = new Map({
    controls: defaultControls({
        attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: false
        }
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two easy ways of doing this.

First one, simply listen for your OpenLayers Map **'click'** (or singleclick) event.
You can then get the cursor coordinates as follow:

```
myMap.on('click', function(evt){
    // Get the pointer coordinate
    let coordinate = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate);
}
```

Second one is, keep track of the pointer coordinate each time it is moved on the map, using the **'pointermove'** event, then just read them when you want:

```
let coord = [];

// We track coordinate change each time the mouse is moved
myMap.on('pointermove', function(evt){
    coord = evt.coordinate;
}

// Anytime you want, simply read the tracked coordinate
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    console.log(coord);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    state={
    mouePos:[1,2]
    }

this.state.map.on('pointermove', (evt)=>{
         this.setState({mousePos:[evt.coordinate[0],evt.coordinate[1]]},()=>{
         console.log(evt.coordinate)
        })  
            })
```

You can use mousePos state as a storage i think